# Mostar una lista de números al azar en orden ascendente y los que números que no estén sean un espacio

Tags: python-3.x, array, lista

A lo que me refiero es que por ejemplo tengo una lista de 20 números, todos al azar, `Lista = [20,28,94,72,81,40]` al mostrarlos se ordenan de menor a mayor, pero necesito que por ejemplo, inicie desde el 10 en este caso y los números entre 20 y 28 que deberían estar representados por un espacio en blanco.
`20 _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 28 ...` y así

Lo primero que se me ocurrió fue esto, que supongo los más experimentados sabrán que no funciona con solo verlo. Si me pudieran guiar en como lo podría hacer sería de gran ayuda.

```
def Mostrar(Lista = []):
    n = 0
    for i in sorted(Lista):
        if i == n:
            print(i, end=" ")
            n+1
        else:
            print("  ")
            n+1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Otra alternativa:

```
Lista = [20,28,94,72,81,40]
orden = sorted(Lista)
out = f"{orden[0]} "
for i in range(1, len(orden)):
    out += "_ " * (orden[i] - orden[i-1] - 1) + f"{orden[i]} "

print(out)
```

Primero hay que ordenar la lista para poder recorrer los valores en orden ascendente.

El `for` recorre los elementos desde el segundo hasta el final. En cada iteración, se calcula la diferencia entre el valor actual y el anterior, lo que usa para generar *n* copias del string "_ ":

```
"_ " * (orden[i] - orden[i-1] - 1) => "_ _ _ "
```

A este le agregamos por la cola el valor actual (convertido a string)

```
out += "_ " * (orden[i] - orden[i-1] - 1) + f"{orden[i]} "
```

y se lo concatenamos al resultado en formación.

#### Demo

```
20 _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 28 _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 40 _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 72 _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 81 _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 94 

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, era realmente lo que estaba buscando! Pero ahora me di cuenta que tengo muchos espacios cuando los números son muy grandes. Se podría disminuir la cantidad de espacios dejándolo ```(orden[i] - orden[i-1] - 10)``` o algo así ??  Pero de todas maneras muchas gracias y muy bien explicado.

Comment: Una solución es tomar el resultado final y hacer un `replace`. Si `a` contiene la secuencia larga, haz un `a.replace("_ _ _ _ _ ", "x ")`. Eso reemplaza cinco "_ " con un "x ". Puedes inventar tu propia tabla de reemplazos.

Answer (score 0):

Se podría usar [zip()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) para hacer parejas de elementos en la lista y comparar su diferencia de forma facil:

```
>>> Lista = [20,28,94,72,81,40]
>>> l2 = sorted(Lista)
>>> list(zip(l2, l2[1:]))
(20, 28), (28, 40), ... (81,94)
>>> 'a' * 3
'aaa' # <-- imprime el char la cantidad de veces
```

Con ese concepto se puede escribir el siguiente código:

```
l2 = sorted(Lista)
l2.append(l2[-1])
for el in zip(l2, l2[1:]):
    print(f"{el[0]}{' '*(el[1]-el[0]-1)}", end='')
```

La línea `l2.append(l2[-1])` es para repetir el último elemento, entonces la ultima pareja del `zip()` será `(94, 94)` y se imprima 94 y cero espacios.
[*] Problemas con este código: `Lista` debe tener al menos un elemento.